# Adding a user to a role with Identity upon registration

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm unsure if this is a duplicate but I tried looking through other questions but just couldn't find the answer I needed.

I've been following a MVC guide (even though I'm working on a normal template asp.net web-form) about adding AspNetUsers to a specific AspNetRoles and managed to create them by modifiying my configuration.cs Migration file.

I used the following code

```
    var RoleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
    string[] roleNames = { "Admin", "QACoordinator", "QAManager", "Staff" };
    IdentityResult roleResult;
    foreach (var roleName in roleNames)
    {
        if (!RoleManager.RoleExists(roleName))
        {
            roleResult = RoleManager.Create(new IdentityRole(roleName));
        }
    }

    var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
    UserManager.AddToRole("c1d97ec4-91e8-4ab9-975f-952ede444a7f", "Admin");
```

This works successfully for me and creates the different roles and assigns the user to an admin role when I use the update-database NuGet feature.

The guide then procceeds to manipulate the AccountControllers file which is only available for MVC. So I assume I'd have to manipulate the code that's available in Register.aspx.cs

The line that is giving me an error is the "UserManager.AddToRole(User.Id, "Staff");" part within

```
protected void CreateUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            var signInManager = Context.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();

            var user = new ApplicationUser()
            {
                UserName = Email.Text,
                Email = Email.Text,
                isVerified = false,
                deptId = deptName.SelectedIndex
            };
            IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {



                UserManager.AddToRole(User.Id, "Staff");

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                //string code = manager.GenerateEmailConfirmationToken(user.Id);
                //string callbackUrl = IdentityHelper.GetUserConfirmationRedirectUrl(code, user.Id, Request);
                //manager.SendEmail(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>.");

                signInManager.SignIn( user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
            }
            else 
            {
                ErrorMessage.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
```

The error I get after hovering over "UserManager" is "UserManager for users where the priamry key for the user is of type string. Using the generic type 'UserManager' requires 1 type arguments." and the error I get from overing over "User.Id" is 'IPrincipal' does not contain a definition for 'Id' and no accessible extension method 'Id' accepting a first argument of type 'IPrincipal' could be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is a typo on your end, since your variable is called `user` and not `User`.
So you need to change your line accordingly:

```
manager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Staff");
```

You can also see this in the commented out lines below

```
string code = manager.GenerateEmailConfirmationToken(user.Id);
string callbackUrl = IdentityHelper.GetUserConfirmationRedirectUrl(code, user.Id, Request);
manager.SendEmail(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>.");
```

Comment: oh yes my bad, you're completely right there! That sorted out the error from the user.Id part, but I'm still getting the same one for UserManager. Maybe I'm calling it in a wrong way?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! Everything is working all perfectly now :D really appreciate the help